# Simple Function in C pointer vs passed value

Tags: c

I would just like to confirm that when I have a function of the sort

```
int subtract(int a, int b)
{
return a-b;
}
```

I am passing values when i call subtract(3,2) rather than pointers.

Thanks,

Comment: @KristopherMicinski yup I acknowledge that, I just don't want to commit one of those horrible basic errors :)

Comment: +1 well done for asking a good basic question with your ideas. It's good to ask when not sure of the basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are

- a parameter of type `int a` means pass an integer by value to the function
- a parameter of type `int* a` means pass a a pointer to some integer to the function.

so for this

```
int subtract(int a, int b) 
{ 
   // even if I change a or b  in here - the caller will never know about it....
   return a-b; 
}
```

you call like this:

```
int result  = substract(2, 1); // note passing values
```

for pointers

```
int subtract(int *a, int *b) 
{ 
   // if I change the contents of where a or b point the  - the caller will know about it....
   // if I say *a = 99;  then x becomes 99 in the caller (*a means the contents of what 'a' points to)
   return *a - *b; 
}
```

you call like this:

```
int x = 2;
int y = 1;
int result  = substract(&x, &y); // '&x means the address of x' or 'a pointer to x'
```

Comment: "means pass by a pointer" doesn't make sense and does not exist ... C ALWAYS pass function parameters by value even in the case of a pointer, in that case the address of the pointer is actually copied .

Comment: @aleroot - of course! I've cleaned up the language. Feel free to edit the answer to make it better.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, C always pass function parameters by value . To pass a pointer you have to specify the star (asterisk) that identify the pointer type.

Bear in mind that **C always pass by value** function parameters even in the case of a pointer, in that case the address of the pointer is actually copied .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are passing values. A pointer would be denoted by an asterisk after the type name and before the variable name.

Comment: Is a local copy made for the function which is thrown out as soon as it is done or is that only if modifications are done ex. a+=1 in the subtract function?

Comment: The values are pushed onto the stack when the function is called, then when it returns the values are thrown away. They are valid and accessible for the entire function duration.

Comment: A copy of the values is always created in the function's scope in c. Not just when you modify them. If you have also defined those variables globally, the ones in the function definition have precedence.